# Extruder clogs after a while on Creality CR-10s Pro v2

Tags: creality-cr-10

The printer has been working perfectly for hundreds of prints. No issues whatsoever. Last week the extruder started clogging. It happens after printing just fine the first half hour or so (3 mm height). The friction through the Bowden seems fine. I'm starting to wonder if the temperature in the nozzle drops and makes feeding impossible.

My settings:

- Prusa slicer with standard configuration for Creality CR-10S Pro V2
- 0.2 mm layer height on 0.4 mm nozzle
- E-PLA 1.75 mm filament
- Nozzle temp 210 °C, bed temp 60 °C

What I've tried:

- Cleaned the extruder various times
- Replaced the bowden tube and it's connectors (it no longer pops out, just clogs)
- Replaced nozzle
- Tried printing this printer test: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2656594?collect

[image: Extruder]

[image: End results for print test]

Answer (score 1):

There is a common issue with Ender printers.  The Bowden tube slips out very very slightly.  And since it's a bowden lined heat break, molten plastic jams between the edge of the tube and the heat break.

There is a great Chep episode on this:

or you can switch to an all metal hot-end.  Long term I recommend this.  It's cheap to get a very good one, and will lead to better upgrades down the line.
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002907726643.html
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003982888788.html
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002854326060.html
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005854409008.html
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005094324313.html

Comment: Thanks, Justin! I will definitely try this out (and probably buy an all metal hot-end as well). Will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Small update. I took apart the all metal hotend on my printer. Turned out the metal tube inside had lots of hard baked filament in it. I cleaned it out and put it back to together. Issue remained. I did the "simple hotend mod" linked above. Still clogging after half an hour's printing, and I can see that the filament inside the hotend has expanded in diameter and is causing the clogging. Have now ordered a bi-metal heatbreak. Crossing my fingers that it will fix the issue.